# Change name of a cell in data frame in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data set:

```
           x y z
1      apple a 4
2     orange d 3
3     banana b 2
4 strawberry c 1
```

How can I change the name "banana" to "grape"? I want to get:

```
           x y z
1      apple a 4
2     orange d 3
3     grape  b 2
4 strawberry c 1
```

Reproducible code:

```
example<-data.frame( x = c("apple", "orange", "banana", "strawberry"), y = c("a", "d", "b", "c"), z = c(4:1) )
```

Comment: It depends if `x` is a factor or a character. In either way, this is very basic question that been probably asked hundreds of times on SO before. In other words, did you Google it?

Comment: Convert the column to `character` class and use `example$x[example$x == "banana"] <- "grape"`

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution using `tidyverse` in R

```
library(tidyverse)
example %>% 
  mutate(x = as.character(x)) %>% 
  mutate(x = replace(x, x == 'banana', 'grape'))
```